# wget does not mirror if IP is provided instead of domain name

Tags: wget, mirroring

I am trying to get a site mirroring with wget, and came across a strange behavior.

Say I am mirroring an internal site named www.example.com in the following way, all seems to be working fine:

```
wget -mkE http://www.example.com
```

However, as I need to access the server by IP and not domain name, I try with:

```
wget -mkE -D www.example.com --header "Host: www.example.com" http://IPv4_ADDR
```

But in this case, it only downloads the first page and exits.

any idea?

Comment: If the links in the first page are absolute links to www.example.com then wget won't think they're within the scope of what you're mirroring. Same goes for relative links if the first page has a <base href="http://www.example.com"> in it.

Comment: @AlanCurry all links are relative, also no `<base>` rag is in use.

Comment: actually shouldn't you give the IP address with `-D`? it sees the relative links as pointing to something under the http:// IPaddr and you've told it with `-D` to only get things under www.example.com

Comment: I see, however, the current setup, can work only with IP address. thanks anyway. you may convert your comment to an answer so I can vote for it etc.